# Sequelize.js - How do I use a column from a left joined table in the where clause?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I have two tables in an SQL database with a one-to-many relationship.  I'm modeling this with sequelize.js. Each table has a date field.  I'd like to write a single findAll query that can do a LEFT JOIN and filter for any row with a date in a certain range.  I can write the query in SQL, but I can't figure out how to write an options object to pass to findAll to reproduce the same query.

Here is the setup:

```js
class Customer extends Model {}

Customer.init( {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  date_of_registration: DataTypes.DATE
} );

class Purchase extends Model {}

Purchase.init( {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  date_of_purchase: DataTypes.DATE
} );

Customer.hasMany( Purchase, {
  foreignKey: { allowNull: false, name: 'customer_id' }
} );
Purchase.belongsTo( Customer, {
  foreignKey: { allowNull: false, name: 'customer_id' }
} );
```

Here is the query I'd like to run:

```sql
SELECT Customer.date_of_registration,
       Purchase.date_of_purchase
FROM Customer
       LEFT JOIN Purchase
                 ON Customer.id = Purchase.customer_id
WHERE Customer.date_of_registration > '2023-10-24'
   OR Purchase.date_of_purchase > '2023-10-24'
GROUP BY Customer.id;
```

I've tried many incorrect things, but the closest I can get is putting the query for the date_of_purchase in an ON clause in the LEFT JOIN instead in an OR clause under the WHERE clause.  Here is what I've tried:

```js
Customer.findAll( {
  where: {
    date_of_registration: {
      [ Op.gt ]: new Date( '2023-10-24' )
    }
  },
  include: [ {
    model: Purchase,
    where: {
      date_of_purchase: {
        [ Op.gt ]: new Date( '2023-10-24' )
      }
    },
    attributes: [],
    required: false
  } ]
} );
```

This query outputs this SQL:

```sql
SELECT "Customer"."id", "Customer"."date_of_registration", "Purchase"."date_of_purchase"
FROM "customer" AS "Customer"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "purchase" AS "Purchase"
    ON "Customer"."id" = "Purchase"."customer_id"
      AND "Purchase"."date_of_purchase" > '2023-10-24 00:00:00.000 +00:00'
WHERE "Customer"."date_of_registration" > '2023-10-24 00:00:00.000 +00:00'
GROUP BY "Customer"."id";
```

How do I modify the Customer.findAll call to output the first query without using a [Raw Query](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about representing the whole original SQL query as a Sequelize query via a model's `findAll` (because it's an aggregation query and it's almost always hard to write such queries w/o literals or as a plain SQL query in Sequelize) but as for representing the given OR condition it could look like this:

```js
Customer.findAll( {
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{
    date_of_registration: {
      [ Op.gt ]: new Date( '2023-10-24' )
    }
  }, {
      '$purchase.date_of_purchase$': {
        [ Op.gt ]: new Date( '2023-10-24' )
      }
  }],
  include: [ {
    model: Purchase,
    attributes: [],
    required: false
  } ]
} );
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Nested column syntax: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level

Comment: I also meant to leave out the aggregation bit in order to make the question simpler.  I'll clean it up.